# Is it possible to have sortable (Interactive) table in rMarkdown?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using `kable()` from **knitr** package to show a table on a html document. Is it possible to make it sortable? Some sample code,

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, comment=""}
kable(data.frame("a"=1:10,"b"=11:20),digits=2)
```
````

Comment: I have a package under development for DataTables. It is in a private repo at the moment, but you can also take a look at this vignette: http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/datatables.html (You need to learn a little bit about DataTables, JavaScript, and HTML)

Comment: @Yihui, the vignette at http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/datatables.html is beautiful but I can't reproduce that example by copying/paste all rmd part at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yihui/knitr/master/vignettes/datatables.Rmd to Rstudio and knit it to html. What might be the problem?

Comment: @KunRen You can use this package: https://github.com/rstudio/DT

Answer (score 65):

The package **DT** (https://github.com/rstudio/DT) is an R interface to the JavaScript library [DataTables](http://datatables.net). You can use it in R Markdown, e.g.

````
```{r}
DT::datatable(iris)
```
````

Comment: Can you please provide an example to set the options for the DataTable?

Comment: Also, is it possible to have multi columns in a single column from a R object? Nested list or something? In kable or in datatable.

Comment: @Yihui Xie can we do the same after a loop?  like use datat table which requires a dataframee or matrix but i have a list ..