# Creating stand-alone HTML from R DT Datatables

Tags: r, dt

How can I save a `datatable` created using the `DT` package so that it can be copied and used by others who don't have R? Is there a function to convert the `datatable` variable into texts of HTML that can be exported?

Comment: just open in browser and save as stand alone html file

Comment: @koundy now why didn't I think of that ... I'll gladly accept that as an answer if you put it in.

Comment: @Pascal am trying to make it available in an environment with no R. Other suggestions other than HTML are welcome.

Comment: Ah my bad for not sharing the context: my DT includes an interactive sparkline for each row, which may require too much effort to visualise from texts. I agree the other textual columns do not really benefit from HTML (maybe except if one of my users want to sort and filter at his/her convenience).

Answer (score 4):

Use `htmlwidgets::saveWidget()`:

```
iris %>% DT::datatable()
result <- iris %>% DT::datatable()
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(result, "result.html")
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to generate a html-file using Rmarkdown, to use Rmarkdown with DT, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120002/is-it-possible-to-have-sortableinteractive-table-in-rmarkdown).

Render the rmd file with `render` from the rmarkdown package. You can also render directly from Rstudio, but in this case Rstudio creates a new Rsession for rendering and objects you defined will not be available.

Also possibly useful to share your data with people who don't use R:

To export data. tables to html or latex tables there are the functions `xtable` from the package xtable and the function `kable` from the knitr package.

To export to csv there are the `write.csv`, `write.table`, ... funcitons in the utils package.

To export to xlsx there are various funcitons in the packages xlsx and XLConnect.